# How to ensure non-duplicate in case of pandas merge and count the number of blanks?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes. I have combined three columns to make a unique key - "Main Key" in both the Dataframes and then merged them on the basis of the "Main Key".

```
df1['Main Key'] = df1['Col1'].str.cat(df1['Col2'],sep="|").str.cat(df1['Col3'],sep="|")
df2['Main Key'] = df2['Col_1'].str.cat(df2['Col_2'],sep="|").str.cat(df2['Col_3'],sep="|")
df_inner = pd.merge(df2,df1,on="Main Key",how="left")
```

There are 6000 entries in df2 and 6600 entries in df1, however the final df_inner has 10000 entries. This is because for 1 entry in df2 there might be multiple matches in df1. How to ensure that this duplication is not present in df_inner?

I want the first instance to be recorded i.e. df_inner should have 6000 entries only as per df2.
Moreover, how can I generate a list or Dataframe of the df2 entries that did not match any df1 entries?

Comment: For this `df2.merge(df1, on="your key", how="left")`, the output should be `len(df2)`. If it is more means you should check the `your key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the first instance to be recorded..

You can use `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates("Main Key", keep="first")` 
and then merge `df_inner = pd.merge(df2,df1,on="Main Key",how="left")`

Comment: `df_inner.loc[df_inner.isna(), [rows from df1] ]` would give you the NaN rows which are non matches.

Comment: It is giving invalid syntax

Comment: print(df_inner.loc[df_inner.isna(), [rows from df_o]])
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `df_inner.loc[df_inner.isna(), [rows from df1] ]` You should replace [rows from df1] this field with your df1 columns name. It should be columns from df1 not rows from df1 my bad. For exapmle `df_inner.loc[df_inner.isna(), ["col1", "col2", "col3"] ]`